# The free monad over an endofunctor on $\mathcal{Set}$

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, constructive-mathematics, monads

Let $F$ be an endofunctor on the category $\mathbf{Set}$. How can I construct the free monad over $F$? Can this construction be generalized to other categories than $\mathbf{Set}$?

Comment: I don't think, in general, you can expect there will be such a thing. But it looks as if there are [restricted cases](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+monad) where you can find free monads.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine But in functional languages like Haskell they have [such thing](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1.3/docs/src/Control.Monad.Free.html#Free): `data Free f a = Pure a | Free (f (Free f a))`. That is why I expect a similar thing in mathematics. Or is it one of the restricted cases that you are pointing out?

Comment: Whatever setting Haskell's monads live in would be a special case. As the nLab article points out, you can at least get a free/forgetful adjunction over $\mathbf{Set}$ when you restrict to accessible functors/monads; sadly it does not seem to present a specific counterexample to the general case.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine What does "accessible" mean?

Comment: There's a link from the nLab article to "accessible functor".

Comment: @MaliceVidrine It is too abstract for me. What does it mean to be accessible for the special case of an endofunctor on the category $\mathcal{Set}$?

Comment: It's an abstract, technical notion; I don't know that there is any good "intuitive" story about it. In the $\omega$-accessible case, it just means that the endofunctor has to preserve finite filtered colimits.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's investigate the specific case of free monads over $\newcommand\catname\mathbf\newcommand\Set{\catname{Set}}\Set\newcommand\Mnd{\catname{Mnd}}\newcommand\into\hookrightarrow\newcommand\id{\mathrm{id}}$, and the relationship to the Haskell free monad.

**Free Monads in General:**

First the general case of what a free monad is. (There are more general notions, but this corresponds to the Haskell notion.) Note that I am not writing the forgetful functor from monads in $C$, $\Mnd_C$, to the endofunctor category, $[C,C]$, explicitly.

Let $F: C\to C$ be an endofunctor. A monad $(T,\mu_T,\iota_T)$ is a free monad for $F$ if for monads $(S,\mu_S,\iota_S)$ we have a natural isomorphism
$$[C,C](F,S) \simeq \Mnd_C(T,S).$$
The functor on the right is corepresentable, so a natural transformation
$$\Mnd_C(T,S)\to [C,C](F,S)$$
is determined by an element $\alpha$ of $[C,C](F,T)$ by Yoneda's lemma. The free monad is usually considered to be the pair $(T,\alpha)$.

**The Haskell Free Monad:**

Let $\newcommand{\Hask}{\catname{Hask}}\Hask$ be the "category" of Haskell types (not quite a category, but it's close enough for our discussion).

Then the definition of the Free monad type in Haskell looks like this

```
data Free f a
  = Pure a
  | Free (f (Free f a))

instance Functor f => Functor (Free f) where
  fmap g (Pure x) = Pure (g x)
  fmap g (Free y) = Free (fmap (fmap g) y)

instance Functor f => Monad (Free f) where
  return = Pure
  (Pure x) >>= g = g x
  (Free y) >>= g = Free (fmap (>>= g) y)
```

For the non-Haskellers, this translates to 
if $F:\Hask\to\Hask$ is a functor, the free monad functor $T$ is defined by the equation $T-=-\amalg FT-$.

Then the natural inclusion $A\into TA$ is the identity for the monad, and the multiplication $\mu: T^2A\to TA$ is defined by observing $T^2A=TA\amalg FT^2A$ and defining $\mu$ to satisfy $\mu = \id \amalg F\mu$.

You'll notice we had to solve several equations here, which aren't problems in $\Hask$ because types and functions can be defined recursively, so these equations define valid types and functions.

We should also show that this definition of `Free f` gives a free functor for `f`. The natural transformation from `f` to `Free f` is just `Free . fmap return`, but I'll leave the verification out for now.

**Translating to Set:**

Now let's translate this to $\Set$. It seems like a reasonable guess that solving the equations for $T$ and $\mu$ are where we might run into problems. I'll have to return to this later though, so I'll post this partial answer.

Now we are working with $F : \Set\to \Set$. 
For each ordinal $\alpha$ define functors $F_\alpha$, with 
$F_0=\newcommand\Id{\mathrm{Id}}\Id$,
$F_{\alpha+1}=-\sqcup FF_\alpha -$,
and $F_\beta = \newcommand\colim{\operatorname{colim}} \colim_{\alpha \in \beta} F_\alpha$ when $\beta$ is a limit ordinal.
When $\alpha \le \beta$, there are natural maps $F_\alpha\to F_\beta$, which 
are constructed at the same time as $F_\beta$, so that the colimit makes sense for limit ordinals. The only map that needs to be constructed explicitly is the map $\iota_\alpha: F_\alpha\to F_{\alpha+1}$.
$\iota_0 : F_0\to F_1$ is clear, this is just the inclusion of $X$ in $X\sqcup FX$ for all $X$.
If $\alpha=\gamma+1$, then $F_\alpha - = -\sqcup FF_\gamma -$. 
Then by induction $F\iota_\gamma : FF_\gamma \to FF_\alpha$, so 
$$\iota_\alpha = \id \sqcup F\iota_\gamma$$ works.
On the other hand, if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, for $\gamma \in \alpha$,
define $j_\gamma : F_\gamma \to F_{\alpha+1}$ by the following formulas.
$j_0$ is the inclusion of $F_0=\Id$ into $F_{\alpha+1}$,
$$j_{\delta+1} = \id \sqcup F (F_\delta\to F_\alpha),$$
and for limit ordinals $\delta$,
$$j_{\delta} =  F_\delta \newcommand\toby\xrightarrow\toby{\iota_{\delta}} F_{\delta+1}\toby{j_{\delta+1}} F_{\alpha+1}.$$
It's not hard to show that these $j$s commute with the $\iota$s, and thus induce the desired map $\iota_{\alpha}: F_\alpha\to F_{\alpha+1}$.

This completes our construction of the functors $F_\alpha$. 
Note that since we have $F\to F_1$, and $\Id\to F_0$, for all $\alpha \ge 1$, we have maps $F\to F_\alpha$ and $\Id \to F_\alpha$. We can think of these as being approximations to a solution to our equation.

We also need an approximation of our multiplication.
Let $i_{\alpha,\beta} : F_\alpha\to F_\beta$ be the maps constructed above.
Define $\mu_{\alpha,\beta}: F_\alpha F_\beta \to F_{\alpha+\beta}$ recursively. (Side note, ordinal addition is noncommutative, but I don't remember which order is correct. I think I may want $\beta+\alpha$ here actually, but this can be deduced from the definition of $\mu$ that I give.)
We have 
$$\mu_{0,\beta} = \id,$$
$$\mu_{\alpha+1,\beta} = i_{\beta,\alpha+\beta+1} \sqcup F\mu_{\alpha,\beta},$$
and in the limit ordinal case,
$$\mu_{\alpha,\beta} = \colim_{\gamma\in\alpha} i_{\gamma+\beta,\alpha+\beta}\circ \mu_{\gamma,\beta}.$$

Then if the sequence $F_\alpha$ stabilizes eventually, we see that we can solve the equations defining the free monad in $\Set$.

There's quite a bit more to add here, but once again, I'll have to leave it at a partial answer for now.

Comment: Thank you for this partial answer. The crux is indeed how do you solve those equations in $\mathbf{Set}$ and I am looking forward to your full answer.

Comment: You wrote "translating to $\mathbf{Set}$" but what you write in this section seems more abstract. Could you specialize more? For example, what is ${\operatorname{colim}}_{\alpha \in \beta} F_\alpha$ in $\mathbf{Set}$?

Comment: @Bob Yeah I realized that after writing it. This still applies to any category with all (small) colimits, but I plan to specialize further in the next bit that I write.